# how to I make my footer responsive without glitching?

Tags: html, css

So im pretty happy with my footer now and its fairly responsive. The Problem: its pretty glitchy. When resizing the window, the text and the links will stack on each other and so on. Can someone help me to fix this? I would love if the middle links would stay side by side and also the social media links to stay in a block.

thank you so much.

```css
.footer {
 position: static;
 flex-shrink: 0;
    bottom: 0px;
    left: 0px;
    right: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    text-align: center;
 box-shadow: inset 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
 z-index: 99;
    /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/
}
.footerline {
 padding: 50px;
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #D5D5D5;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/
}
#footerlineshadow {
 color: rgba(240,240,240, 0.9);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff, 0 0 0 #000, 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.subfooter {
    height: 40px;
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.footercontent {
    display: flex;
    font-family: lato;
    color: #ABABAB;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 100%;
}
#footertext {
 text-align: center;
 margin-right: 20%;
 /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/
}
#footerlinks {
 text-align: center;
 /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/

}
#footerlinks a {
    margin: 0px 40px;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 12px;
    color: #ABABAB;
    text-decoration: none; /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/
}
#footerlinks a:hover {
 opacity: 0.7;
 font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 12px;
 text-decoration: none;
 /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/
}
#footersocialmedia {
 margin-left: 20%;
}
 /* Style all font awesome icons */
.fa {
  padding: 5px;
  font-size: 30px;
  width: 25px;
 height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Add a hover effect if you want */
.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

/* Set a specific color for each brand */

/* Facebook */
.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

/* Twitter */
.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}
.fa-youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="applicationStylesheet" href="header_footer.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" id="mainStylesheet" href="kontakt.css"/>
<link href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Source+Code+Pro:wght@500&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<footer class="footer">
   <div class="footerline">
     <p id="footerlineshadow">&ltp&gtThis is a Footer&lt/p&gt</p>
      </div>
 <div class="subfooter">
  <div class="footercontent">
   <div id="footertext">
    <p>Copyright © 2020 Henning Frenzel</p>
   </div>
   
   <div id="footerlinks">
    <p>
    <a href="home.html">Home</a>
    <a href="ueber_mich_.html">Über Mich</a>
         <a href="portfolio_galerie.html">Portfolio</a>
         <a href="kontakt.html">Kontakt</a>
    <a href="Impressum.html">Impressum</a>
    </p>
   </div>
   <div id="footersocialmedia">
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-facebook"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-twitter"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-youtube"></a>
    <a href="#" class="fa fa-instagram"></a>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
</footer>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

**Here is the code for responsive footer**

```css
.footer {
  display:flex;
  flex-direction:row;
    min-height:50px;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    justify-content:center;
    align-items:center;
   
    text-align: center;
        flex-wrap:wrap;

 box-shadow: inset 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.footerline {
    display: flex;
    font-family: 'Source Code Pro', monospace;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    font-size: 15px;
    color: #D5D5D5;
    width:100%;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction:row;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/
}
#footerlineshadow {
 color: rgba(240,240,240, 0.9);
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #fff, 0 0 0 #000, 1px 1px 1px #fff;
}
.subfooter {
    background-color: #E5E5E5;
    box-shadow: inset 0 4px 5px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
.footercontent {
    display: flex;
    font-family: lato;
    color: #ABABAB;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    width:100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    text-align: center;
    justify-content: center;
    min-height:50px;
}
#footertext {
 text-align: center;
 /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/
}
#footerlinks {
 text-align: center;
 /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/

}
#footerlinks a {
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 12px;
    padding:0 15px;
    color: #ABABAB;
    text-decoration: none; /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/
}
#footerlinks a:hover {
 opacity: 0.7;
 font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 100;
    font-size: 12px;
 text-decoration: none;
 /*outline: 2px dashed orange;*/
}
#footersocialmedia {
  display:flex;
  align-items:center;
  justify-content:center;
  flex-direction:row;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
}
 /* Style all font awesome icons */
.fa {
  padding: 20px;
  font-size: 30px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
}

/* Add a hover effect if you want */
.fa:hover {
  opacity: 0.7;
}

/* Set a specific color for each brand */

/* Facebook */
.fa-facebook {
  background: #3B5998;
  color: white;
}

/* Twitter */
.fa-twitter {
  background: #55ACEE;
  color: white;
}
.fa-youtube {
  background: #bb0000;
  color: white;
}

.fa-instagram {
  background: #125688;
  color: white;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**And if you want to stay footer at the bottom use write these code to footer attribute in css**

**position:absolute;

bottom:0;

left:0;

**